# Accessing Placeholders from Liquibase Java API

Tags: java, liquibase

I am using the Liquibase java API to update my database from a databaseChangeLog file. I am also setting the default database schema using the code below:

```
    Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(conn));
        database.setDefaultSchemaName(CustomerPortalServiceBeanFactory.getInstance().getServiceConfigurationData().getSchemaName());
```

This works fine except when I have a change log that creates a view as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
  xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">
    <changeSet author="mhills" id="customerUser-view">
        <createView 
               replaceIfExists="true"
               viewName="CUSTOMER_USER_VW">
               select 
                customeruser.id,
                customeruser.status,
                customeruser.customer_id, 
                customeruser.contact_id,
                customeruser.email_address, 
                customeruser.online_name,
                customeruser.date_created
                FROM customer_user customeruser
        </createView>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

The schemaName is properly prefixing the view name but I also need to prefix the table used in the from clause. Is the schema name available as a placeholder or is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

After reading the documentation I was able to access the set "schemaName" by adding the code below.

```
// set the schema read from the properties file.
System.setProperty("schemaName", CustomerPortalServiceBeanFactory.getInstance().getServiceConfigurationData().getSchemaName());

// Establish the Liquibase database connection
Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(conn));
                database.setDefaultSchemaName(CustomerPortalServiceBeanFactory.getInstance().getServiceConfigurationData().getSchemaName());
```

By adding the "schemaName" value as a system property it was available as a placeholder in the changesets. Example below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
  xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">
    <changeSet author="mhills" id="customerUser-view">
        <createView 
               replaceIfExists="true"
               viewName="CUSTOMER_USER_VW">
               select 
                customeruser.id,
                customeruser.status,
                customeruser.customer_id, 
                customeruser.contact_id,
                customeruser.email_address, 
                customeruser.online_name,
                customeruser.date_created
                FROM "${schemaName}".customer_user customeruser
        </createView>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```